# Serialize contents of a Canvas

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

In a WPF program, I can use `System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter` to serialize the contents of a WPF `Canvas` into text. But this is not available in a windows store/metro app, how then would be able to serialize the contents of a Windows-Store Canvas ?

---

(My app is similar to a painting application, where the user can draw using a mouse. The 'drawings' are `UIElements` like `Line` and `Ellipse` added as children of a `Canvas`. I'm looking for a serialization method as I want to be able to save/restore these `UIElements`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no `System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter` in either windows store apps or UWP apps, I ended up using [Sharp Serializer](http://sharpserializer.com). It's quite easy to use in both WPF and Windows RT.

Some other popular serializing engines, from this blog ([Choosing the right serialization engine for your Windows Store app](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2014/01/19/serializing-and-deserializing-data-in-a-windows-store-app.aspx)), are XmlSerializer, DataContractSerializer, and JsonSerializer.